# jquery Datatables add row. https://datatables.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to ad a row to my java script data table (https://datatables.net)

```
ReportTable = $('#ReportsTable').dataTable({
 //"data": Reportdata,
"bLengthChange": false,
"columns": [
  { "data": "name", "sTitle": "Name", "sWidth": "300px"},
  { "data": "type", "sTitle": "Report Type" },
  { "data": "timestamp", "sTitle": "Purchase Date" }
 ]
});

ReportTable.row.add("{name:'Test', type:'test', timestamp:'test'}").draw();
```

I have been following pages https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add() and http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html with no luck.

The error i am getting reads as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

ReportTable = $('#ReportsTable').**dataTable**(
must be
ReportTable = $('#ReportsTable').**DataTable**(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with:

```
ReportTable.row.add(['Test','test','test']).draw();
```

Because you added your columns name to your Datatable definition.

Answer (score 0):

Swap out the DataTables include script with the following:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

I'm guessing you are using an outdated version that does not include the API you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to rewrite to the following:

```
$('#ReportsTable').dataTable({
 //"data": Reportdata,
"bLengthChange": false,
"columns": [
  { "data": "name", "sTitle": "Name", "sWidth": "300px"},
  { "data": "type", "sTitle": "Report Type" },
  { "data": "timestamp", "sTitle": "Purchase Date" }
 ]
});

var ReportTable = $('#ReportsTable').dataTable();
ReportTable.row.add("{name:'Test', type:'test', timestamp:'test'}").draw();
```